# How can Javascript communicate with C++ in React Native?

Tags: react-native, javascriptcore

In old architecture of React Native, we all know it uses a bridge to connect Javascript and Native language, the data format is json, Javascript communicates with C++, C++ communicates with Native language(Java/Objective C). Please tell me if I misunderstand it.
My question is:

How can Javascript communicate with C++? I read a [blog](https://medium.com/@samwhadams/react-native-under-the-hood-80677cf9bf96) , it says JS talks async to C++ through shared memory. I also read some other blogs, they say JavascriptCore provides C++ APIs to communicate with Javascript.